# Blazor StateHasChanged() refreshes component whilst user is trying to edit grid

Tags: blazor, webassembly

I have a blazor web assembly app with a radzen grid which displays data from SQL.
I have a timer which is set up to run every 5 seconds and will call my signalrhub to refresh data on the grid component every 5 seconds.
While the user is editing the component (using the edit function which radzen provides), the component would obviously refresh and then kick the user out from editing and because its happening every 5 seconds, its almost impossible for users to make changes unless its done within 5 seconds. I know i can up the timer a bit but my grid needs to update everytime because it is important information which changes all the time (similar to stocks).

Is it possible to lock the radzen grid while a user is on editting mode?

Any help is appreciated thank you

Comment: You can do that in various ways, as for instance, dispose of the timer object when the user is on editing mode, and renew the timer's action when on read mode. Instead you can suppress the UI refreshing, when the user is on editing mode, by overriding the ComponentBase.ShouldRender Method to return false value.

Comment: You should make this event driven by injectecting the hub context into the API controller you can then notifiy users of updates instead of polling.

Comment: Hi there, how do you make the hub event driven? How does it know when changes are made in the database in order to push data to the hub?